# Is it possible to send "this.src" to js function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace photo1.gif.
Why this code is not working,it's because of this in call?

HTML code:

```
<img src="photo1.gif" onmouseover="x(this.src)">
```

JS code:

```
<script>

  function x(source) {
    source="photo2.gif";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: `source` is just a variable. pass `this` and do `el.src = ...`

Comment: `onmouseover="x(this)"` and access `source.src` in the x function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things to consider:

First, ensure `x` is defined on the `window` object and that you're calling `window.x`.

Second, `this.src` is a value parameter meaning it's value is copied to the `x` function. If you want to modify it you need to pass `this` to `x`:

```
<img src="photo1.gif" onmouseover="window.x(this)">

<script>
window.x = function (element) {
  element.src = "photo2.gif";
}
</script>
```

[Working JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvr5thjm/1/)

Comment: Updated with working code. TBH I don't understand why it's necessary to add `window.x()` in the `onmouseover` attribute.

Comment: it was just a name of function

Comment: Yes, it appears if you change `x`'s name to `changesrc` you can remove `window` from the `onmouseover` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

youre HTML code is

```
img src="photo1.gif" onmouseover="x(this)">
```

function code is

```
paramName.src = "photo2.gif";
```